# Reportmanager and delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, reportmanager

does [reportmanager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reportman/) (http://sourceforge.net/projects/reportman/) support delphi 2010?

Thanks
Alejandro Jourdan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the most recent download on SourceForge only has premade projects to compile native components up through Delphi 2009.  I expect it should be easy enough to revise the D2009 project to compile under D2010.

Also, as you may know, you could use ReportManager with D2010 without having the native components at all.

You might get more complete and accurate answers in the Report Manager user group on Yahoo:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/reportman/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compile the latest 3.0 version with Delphi 2010 Professional. Not a really easy task.

In order to do so, you have to follow these steps:

- Edit the .inc file and see if you can exclude unused libraries.
  In my case I undefined IBX and used ZEOS for database.

  - Then you will get an error about IntPr being not defined. Replace it with Pointer.
  - You will get hundreds of FormatSettings not defined errors. You have to remove such identifier. I.e. go in search and replace and type: "FormatSettings." including the dot and in replace leave it blank. Repeat for the many files that will show the same error, or do a multi-file search and replace at once.
  - You will possibly get references to IBX units or packages even in case you removed it from the .inc file. You may just delete the offending lines.
  - You will get a nasty missing unit WinApi.Common... Remove it from the uses clauses, you don't have it.
  - At a certain point the above point will cause an undefined FOLDERID_Public.

Go to the **const** section of the offending file and add this:

```
FOLDERID_Public: TGUID = '{DFDF76A2-C82A-4D63-906A-5644AC457385}';
```

That should do it, now you are the proud owner of Report Manager 3.0!

Answer (score 1):

Installed today in D2010 on XP without particolar problems.
First downloaded and installed ver. 2.9b executable file.
Second downloaded Delphi package, added source path to the library, opened and compiled group project file.
Received 3 errors (even the same error type): vcljpg Not Found.
Simply rename vcljpg with vclimg.
after that, compiled done, installed.